# Find number of x such that $\{x\}+\{x^2\}=1,x\in(0,20). $Where $\{\}$ denotes fractional part.

Tags: fractional-part

Find number of x such that $\{x\}+\{x^2\}=1,x\in(0,20).$Where $\{\}$ denotes fractional part.

I did it by lot of case work searching for some simpler solution

Comment: Well, you must have found some solutions, no?  Can you, say, find a solution between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: To further lulu's hint: for $x \in (0,1)$, your equation translates to $x + x^2 = 1,$ since $\{x\} = x \in (0,1) \implies \{x^2 \} = x^2 \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the interval (0,1), the function increases only once, and by monotonicity and continuity has exactly one solution on that interval. For every interval afterwards, $\{x^2\}$ "resets" multiple times. Each time it does, the function drops from a number bigger than one to a number less than one, so the equation picks up a solution for every reset. On the interval $(k-1,k)$,  there are $k^2-(k-1)^2 =2k-1$ continuous pieces, hence there are $2k-1$ solutions. So the number of solutions on the interval $(0,n)$ is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k - 1) = n(n+1) - n = n^2$$

In this case the number of solutions is $400$.